# As an IM app, how to tell frontend which part of conversations lost efficiently?

Tags: architecture, chat

As an IM app, assume one user have 100000+ conversations. If due to some frontend bug, some conversations are deleted in client app, how to sync those lost conversations from backend when user open app?  Either frontend upload all conversation ids nor pull from backends are efficiently. Is there any good idea? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could run a checksum on the conversation ids on each end and compare the results.  Literally just add them up and compare the sums of IDs.  If they don't match you will need to fall back to checking lists (or segmenting the lists and checksumming if you want to be fancy about it).